# Am I going to use "with" or "wearing"?

Tags: prepositions, verbs

It's may day 2016 and every student can wear graduated cap this weekend in Finland.

I read, that the word "cap" is deprecated and the synonym for "cap" would be "headwear".

I'm going to tell my followers in English that I'm going to have a party with my college graduating cap or "Going to party wearing my college graduating headwear". I'm not sure if it's "Going to party with my college headwear". Please help me, with or wear with the word "headwear".

Comment: Are you asking about "with" vs "wear", or "cap" vs "headwear"?

Answer (score 2):

"Headwear" is definitely not commonly used, at least not here in Canada. It's more commonly referred to as a "graduate cap" or "graduation cap".

Using "with" or "wearing" doesn't matter too much, but "wearing" is more specific. "With" just means you are taking it, but you could be carrying it under your arm the whole time. But "wearing" means that you intend to wear it (probably for the whole party).

Also, you would say "a party".

So, you could say something like,

> I am going to a party wearing my graduate cap.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the OP really means he's gonna party (tonight/tomorrow), rather than gonna go to a party.

Answer (score 2):

For certain types of things put on one's head, some people may no longer use "cap". However, if I understand you correctly, you are speaking of the thing you had on your head when you graduated.  In many situations it may look like a square with a tassel and upon graduation the tassel is switched from one side to the other. 
[image: here]
The entire dress is usually referred to as **cap and gown**. Not all graduates will wear a "mortarboard" and even in those instances, it is still referred to as a "cap" or "hat".  For example, cadets at West Point will traditionally [throw their hats in the air at commencement](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-to-all-those-hats-after-the-graduation-ceremonies-at-West-Point-Annapolis-and-Colorado-Springs)
[image: here]


You will want to say

> I am going to the party **in** my college graduation cap
>   I am going to the party **wearing** my graduation cap

Answer (score 1):

A word like *headwear* or *headgear* is a **hypernym** for a word like *cap* or *hat*; that is, it usually refers to a range of items in a particular category. For example, if I went to the *headwear* section of a department store, I might be able to get any of these items: a cap, a hat, a visor, a beret, or a headscarf.

*Headwear* usually refers to items such as sun hats, rain hats, ball caps, snow caps, and stetsons. *Headgear* might be used when the item is more protective, such as a helmet.

I'm unlikely to say, "I'll be wearing some headwear tomorrow." Instead, I would say, "I'll be wearing a cap tomorrow," or, "I'll be wearing a hat tomorrow." (Whether I use *hat* or *cap* depends on what I plan to wear. Some headwear is almost always a "hat", and some is usually a "cap" instead.)

[image]

That said, if I was organizing a golf tournament, I might say, "It's supposed to be hot and sunny tomorrow; bring some headgear."

That's a convenient way to let everyone know they should bring some type of protective headwear – although what each golfer chooses to wear might vary quite a bit:

[image]

As for the decline in usage of *cap* that you speak of, I don't think it's as drastic as you might think. There's a famous line in an old Christmas poem:

> *And mamma in her ’kerchief, and I in my cap,
>
>   Had just settled our brains for a long winter’s nap*

Mama's kerchief and the narrator's cap are usually imagined to like something like this:

[image]

I agree; **that** sense of the word *cap* is in decline – partly because fewer people wear sleeping caps nowadays. But if you are talking about a **graduation cap** (i.e. a *mortarboard*), that is still commonly referred to as a *cap*, and that's the word I would expect to read in your announcement:

> Going to party wearing my **graduation cap**.

As for "with" or "wear", you could use either one:

> Going to party with my **graduation cap**.

but I think "wear" is the better choice. We go to parties *with* our friends, but we go to parties *wearing* headwear.